# Increment counter in find -exec

Tags: bash, filesystems, find

I have a script that runs a number of processes like this

```
./myproc1      --out=1.xml
./myotherproc  --out=2.xml
./mythirdproc  --out=3.xml
./myfourthproc --out=4.xml
# ... some more files
```

I want to replace it with a loop, and so far I've come to this

```
find . -name 'my*' -exec ./'{}' \;
```

But I don't know how to build the name of the output file dynamically. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason for the `xml`s to be `#.xml`? It seems ambiguous which file made each `xml`. It seems like a better approach would be `--out={}.xml` which would make `xml`s with a filename that matches the process that created it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash:

```
c=1; for i in ./my*; do echo "$i" --out=$[c++].xml; done
```

If everything looks okay remove `echo`.

---

Long version [as proposed by User Centimane](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/168776):

```
counter=1
for i in ./my*; do
  echo "$i" --out=$[counter++].xml
done
```

The `counter++` will increment your counter each time.

Comment: @Centimane: I intended to post an one-liner.